# How to add a CSS class to a partial rendered in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, render, partials

I have a multiple partials that I am rendering and would like to add a CSS class to one of them. Is there a way to do this?

Here is the page I am rendering

```
<%= render :partial => "/account/plan_yearly" -%>
```

which adds this html to the page

```
<div class="offer">
    <!--MORE HTML-->
</div>
```

What I would like to do is something like this:

```
<%= render :partial => "/account/plan_yearly", :class => "highlight" -%>
```

Which would render the html below:

```
<div class="offer highlight">
    <!--MORE HTML-->
</div>
```

But it doesn't work the way I want it to. Any thoughts? Much appreciated!

Thanks Everyone

Answer (score 4):

You will need to render the partial using locals and then use them within the partial:

```
<%= render partial: "/account/plan_yearly", locals: { myclass: 'highlight' } %>
```

What this does is make a local variable named `myclass` with a value of 'highlight' for the scope of the partial.

So in the partial you can then make use of this:

```
<div class="offer <%= myclass %>">
    <!--MORE HTML-->
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you both for helping me out! really appreciate it. I am having a new issue now. The partial is rendering `<div class="offer #{myclass}">` with the `#{ }` and not as ruby. Any thoughts?

Comment: oops yeah should be erb shouldn't it - shall update the answer

Comment: Hey @David , I've been trying to get this exact same thing to work but i keep getting the following error: undefined local variable or method `myclass'. Any thoughts as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if this might still help, but I just had the same problem, as it can be read on the [rails documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html), in order to pass correctly values through locals it is really important to state explicitly taht you're randering a partial;

**Correct:**

```
<%= render partial:"path/to/partials", locals:{bla: "bla"} %>
```

**Incorrect**

```
<%= render "path/to/partials", locals:{bla: "bla"} %>
```

As the second line doesn't explicitly state that the rendering object is a partial, passing locals won't work at all...

Answer (score 0):

You can pass it as variable

```
= render "/account/plan_yearly", highlight: true
```

Then in partial

```
<div class="offer #{'highlight' if highlight}">
  <!--MORE HTML-->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Passing it in as a variable worked!

```
<%= render partial: => "/account/plan_yearly", locals: { myclass: 'highlight' } %>

<div class="offer #{myclass}">
    <!--MORE HTML-->
 </div>
```

Thanks Everyone!